# FBX: как трансформировать точку в мировые координаты?

Tags: c++, 3d, fbx

Пишу конвертер из [FBX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) в свой формат данных с помощью [FBX SDK](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/). Возникла необходимость получить координаты вершин меша в мировых координатах. Как узнать [координаты вершин меша](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_vector4_html) в локальных координатах объекта я понял. Нужно сперва получить меш вызвав функцию GetMesh у объекта [FbxNode](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_node_html). А затем уже у [меша](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_mesh_html) можно получить список вершин.

Как получить [матрицу трансформации](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_a_matrix_html) из локальных коордитан в мировые - тоже понятно. Нужно вызвать функцию EvaluateGlobalTransform у объекта [FbxNode](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_node_html).

Но почему-то не вижу, как имея матрицу трансформации и точку в локальных координатах получить точку в мировых координатах. Почему-то нет оператора умножения матрицы на вектор или operator() у матрицы, который бы трансформировал вектор.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как трансформируют точки в FBX?

Comment: Добавьте больше подробностей, ссылок и т.п. [Предложите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/7262) описание метки [tag:fbx] для лучшего понимания о чём действительно речь.